# i have a form to input data in and i want the data to appear at another page from local storage

Tags: javascript

my problem is I console log the local storage and the inputs appear fine but I can't see them on the other page although at local storage they are stored fine

the form :

```html
  <form id="formID">
    <div class="Contact__Card">
      <div class="Input__Container">
        <label for="foodName" class="Label" >Food</label>
        <input
          name="foodName"
          class="Input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="What would you like to add?"
          id="foodName"
          required
        />
      </div>

  <div class="input__Container">
    <label for="foodType">Choose Food type:</label>
<select class="Input" id="foodType" name="foodlist">
  <option value="Fruit and vegetables">Fruit and vegetables</option>
  <option value="Starchy food">Starchy food</option>
  <option value="Dairy">Dairy</option>
  <option value="Protein">Protein</option>
  <option value="Fat">Fat</option>
</select></div>

      <div class="Input__Container">
        <label for="price" class="Label">price</label>
        <input type="text" min="1" step="any"  class="Input" id="foodPrice" required/>

        
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="Input__Container">
       
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="Input"/>

        
      </div>
  
      
      
    </div>
  </form>
```

the js file of the form page :

```js
"use strict";

var allFood = [];
function food(foodName, foodType, price) {
  this.foodName = foodName;
  this.foodType = foodType;
  this.price = price;
  allFood.push(this);
}
food.prototype.fID = function () {
  this.id = Math.floor(1111 + Math.random() * 9999);
};

const formEl = document.getElementById("formID");
formEl.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let foodName = event.target.foodName.value;
  let foodType = event.target.foodType.value;
  let price = event.target.foodPrice.value;

  const newFood = new food(foodName, foodType, price);

  newFood.fID();

  saveData();
}

function saveData() {
  let stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(allFood);
  localStorage.setItem("Food", stringifiedData);
}
```

the table of the other page i want the data to apear in :

```html
<table id="fTable">

    <tr id="hdrTable">

    </tr>


</table>
```

the js file of the output page  is the issue from the get data function ?:

```js
"use strict";

const fdTable = document.getElementById('fTable');
const tableHead = document.getElementById('hdrTable');
var allFood = [];

function food(foodName, foodType, price) {
  this.foodName = foodName;
  this.foodType = foodType;
  this.price = price;
  allFood.push(this);
}
food.prototype.fID = function () {
  this.id = Math.floor(1111 + Math.random() * 9999);
};

table();

function table() {
  let headerID = document.createElement("th");
  headerID.textContent = "ID";

  let headerName = document.createElement("th");
  headerName.textContent = "Food Name";

  let headerType = document.createElement("th");
  headerType.textContent = "Type of Food";

  let headerPrice = document.createElement("th");
  headerPrice.textContent = "price";

  hdrTable.appendChild(headerID);
  hdrTable.appendChild(headerName);
  hdrTable.appendChild(headerType);
  hdrTable.appendChild(headerPrice);
}

food.prototype.Render = function () {
  let row = document.createElement("tr");
  let id = document.createElement("td");
  let name = document.createElement("td");
  let type = document.createElement("td");
  let price = document.createElement("td");

  id.textContent = this.id;
  name.textContent = this.foodName;
  type.textContent = this.foodType;
  price.textContent = this.price;

  row.appendChild(id);
  row.appendChild(name);
  row.appendChild(type);
  row.appendChild(price);

  fTable.appendChild(row);

};
getData();

function getData(){
  let retrivedData = localStorage.getItem("stringifiedData");
  let parsedData = JSON.parse(retrivedData);
  if(parsedData!=null){
  for (let i = 0; i < parsedData.length; i++) {
    let newFoodOP = new food(
      parsedData[i].foodName,
      parsedData[i].foodType,
      parsedData[i].price
    );
   
  }
}
for (let i = 0; i < allFood.length; i++) {
  allFood[i].Render();
}
    console.log(allFood);
}
```

Comment: How are you navigating to "the other page"? Does it have the same URL?

Comment: yes  normal linking navi